# Ionic Native: tried calling Uid.IMEI, but the Uid plugin is not installed. (In some devices)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am facing issue in udid plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid) in some devices only (one plus , samsung galaxy)

```
vendor.js:61890 Ionic Native: tried calling Uid.IMEI, but the Uid plugin is not installed.
```

but it is working properly in other android device. In that case i am getting null. I have tried to call function inside **platform ready** but no luck .

Answer (score 0):

If you only need UUID of device you can try this plugin"

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply but i need IMEI number of device . UUID may be a work around but i have to check that with DB .

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: @SamiJmii track  IMEI number is not allowed now after android 10 , so you should capture another id . I was getting udid of device .